# iptables - hashlimits, why it calculate all to seconds

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I've tried to set 'synflood' limits with hashlimits, those are my snippet of rules:

```
iptables -A SYNFLOOD_CHECK -p tcp --syn -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 10/s --hashlimit-burst 6 \
--hashlimit-htable-expire $HTABLE_EXPIRE --hashlimit-mode $HASH_MODE --hashlimit-name synflood_s -j SYNFLOOD_DETECTED

iptables -A SYNFLOOD_CHECK -p tcp --syn -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 25/min --hashlimit-burst 6 \
--hashlimit-htable-expire $HTABLE_EXPIRE --hashlimit-mode $HASH_MODE --hashlimit-name synflood_s -j SYNFLOOD_DETECTED

iptables -A SYNFLOOD_CHECK -p tcp --syn -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 500/h --hashlimit-burst 6 \
--hashlimit-htable-expire $HTABLE_EXPIRE --hashlimit-mode $HASH_MODE --hashlimit-name synflood_m -j SYNFLOOD_DETECTED
```

What I want to do ? I want to match SYN packets with one source ip which are above this limits:

```
> 10 Packets per second -j SYNFLOOD_DETECTED rule 
> 25 packets per minute -j SYNFLOOD_DETECTED rule 
> 500 packets per day -j SYNFLOOD_DETECTED rule
```

Why I want this limits?
Assuming i get 1pps from 10k IP's, it is 10k packets per second, but only one per second from one src ip, I could match this packets by rule 25/min ( = 0.41 p/s) but this could affect to my normal traffic to webserver.

And what I see, if I set --hashlimit-above 25/min, this is calculated to 25/60 = 0.41 pps.
So this rule override before "--hashlimit-above 10/s", is it possible to make this limits as I want ?

Comment: Post your entire iptables ruleset for assistance.